# Copying file drops to 0B/s

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I wanted to restore my data from a backup (HDD to HDD) but this one file (a movie >11GB) drops the transfer speed to 0B/s at 33%. I guess a movie with some missing bytes should work anyway?

I guess this one file is corrupted (because I successfully copied every other file) which is no (big) loss but is there a way to **"hard copy" the file anyway**?

**EDIT:** even Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier stops at 33% (still responding but the copy progress stands still). The file transfer stops but Windows 10 Task Manager shows the HDD at 100% workload.

Comment: Please update your question to state where you are restoring the data from - external drive, over the network, or..?

Comment: @FastEthernet from HDD to HDD (updated Q)

Comment: I know it's a older question but have you tried running `fsck`? Boot from a Linux live CD/USB and run `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` (where `/dev/sda1` is the partition with the movie). Also, you could use [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) to check the drive's SMART status (and then post a screenshot).

Comment: 33% of 11gb is roughly 4gb, which is the maximum file size in FAT32.

Is it possible that the destination drive is formatted as FAT32? I could see it getting confused upon reaching the 4GB limit. Right clicking the drive > Properties and looking at 'File System' will tell you what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try running CHKDSK on the drive where the movie is located that you wish to copy. This will help identify any damaged sectors that may lead to read errors.
You can do that in the following way;

- Open 'This PC'
- Right-click on the drive where your movie is located
- Click 'Properties'
- Click the 'Tools' tab
- Click the 'Check' button

If there are any errors found, Windows will try to repair them. You may be asked to restart your computer, depending on what drive it is due to access restrictions.

If that doesn't work or as an alternative to running CHKDSK, you can try compressing the file to a ZIP folder.

- Right click the movie file
- Go to 'Send to'
- Click 'Compressed (zipped) folder'

Now you can try copying the ZIP-file containing the movie to another drive. If zipping the movie file fails, the file may be corrupted beyond the abilities Windows has to offer to repair it.

Comment: chkdsk phase 4 (searching for corrupted clusters in user files) takes 42 hours ...

Comment: Drive Read Error c00000b5 the drive has not enough space to replace corrupted clusters found in file \Filme\DIETR~1\DIETRI~2.MKV (1. the file has enough free space >50GB, 2. the file name is strange but I guess its an internal name and not the actual file name)

Comment: @Pali that's just an 8.3 file name, see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: In this situation the free space refers to the amount of clusters available to replace the bad ones. Are there other important things on that drive? If so, I suggest backing up all important files just in case it gets worse. Consider replacing the drive as these errors are one of the first signs of a hard drive failure.

Comment: @Luchador95 I deleted ALL files expect the bad one (now there is 98% free space) but chkdsk still tells me that there is not enough space to replace the bad clusters, guess I can throw the HDD away?